# php replace affects on replaced string

Tags: php, replace, preg-replace, str-replace

The string is: `1y1m1w1d1s` (a simple time format!), and the result should be: `1years1months1weeks1days1seconds`.

I tried `str_replace` in this way:

`$result = str_replace(array('s', 'h', 'd', 'w', 'm', 'y'), array('seconds', 'hours', 'days', 'weeks', 'months', 'years'), '1y1m1w1d1s');`

but result was: `1years1months1weeks1dayearss1secondayearsss`, as you see, `d` replaced twice, first at 1**d** then at secon**d**s.

How to limit replace only to first occurrence? Someway that supports arrays as needle.

Comment: you can give count 1 as php.net says http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php you can say with count the number of change performed (this is an example)

Comment: @MarcoMura: You mean that: `$b = 1; $result = str_replace(array('s', 'h', 'd', 'w', 'm', 'y'), array('seconds', 'hours', 'days', 'weeks', 'months', 'years'), '1y1m1w1d1s', $b);`? It returns same result. (note that last parameter should send by reference)

Answer (score 3):

`str_replace` can make circular replacements since it parses all the string for each search/replace. So, once the first search/replace is performed, the new version of your string is used for other search/replace.

The solution is to use `strtr` that parses the string only once. (and is faster)

```
$trans = array('s'=>'seconds', 'h'=>'hours', 'd'=>'days', 'w'=>'weeks', 'm'=>'months', 'y'=>'years');
$yourdate = strtr($yourdate, $trans);
```